# How to show $P^{n}_{B} \simeq P^{n}_{A} \times_{\operatorname{Spec} A} \operatorname{Spec} B$ as in Hartshorne?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In order to define projective $n$-space, Hartshorne claimed that 'if $A \rightarrow B$ is a homomorphism of rings, and $\operatorname{Spec} B \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$ is the corresponding morphism of affine schemes, then $P^{n}_{B} \simeq P^{n}_{A} \times_{\operatorname{Spec} A} \operatorname{Spec} B$', where $P^{n}_{A}$ means $\operatorname{Proj} A[x_0,...,x_n]$.

**My questions are what is the morphism between $P^{n}_{A}$ and $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and how do I show that $P^{n}_{B} \simeq P^{n}_{A} \times_{\operatorname{Spec} A} \operatorname{Spec} B$?**

I think, if $f:A \rightarrow A[x_0,...,x_n]$ is the embedding of rings, then the morphism between $P^{n}_{A}$ and $\operatorname{Spec} A$ just sends homogeneous prime ideals of $P^{n}_{A}$ to its preimage under $f$, however I am not entirely sure how to show this is indeed a morphism of scheme.

Also, since there is a homomorphism of rings $A \rightarrow B$, I think we have a graded homomorphism of graded rings $A[x_0,...,x_n] \rightarrow B[x_0,...,x_n]$, which by Hartshorne exercise 2.14(b), induces a natural morphism of schemes $P^{n}_{B} \rightarrow P^{n}_{A}$.

Comment: To show that $f$ is a morphism of schemes, note that you have ring maps $f_i:A \to A[x_0/x_i,...,\widehat{x_i/x_i},...,x_n/x_i]$ which induce maps from the distinguished affine opens $U_i \subset \mathbb P_A^n$ to $\operatorname{Spec}A$, and it's basically tautological that these $f_i$ agree on overlaps. Does that satisfy you? You are also correct about the other maps. Basically you are just tensoring the codomain of each $f_i$ with $B$ and gluing together in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, do you mind writing a more complete answer so that I may follow the detail?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to prove $P_B^n \cong P_A^n \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}\mathrm{Spec}(B)$, you may wish to use the standard open covers of $P_B^n,P^n_A$. It is easy to see that
$$\begin{align*} P_B^n & = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \left \{x_i \neq 0 \right \} = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathrm{Spec}(B[x_0/x_i,...,\widehat{x_i/x_i},...,x_n/x_i])\\ 
& = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Spec}(A[x_0/x_i,...,\widehat{x_i/x_i},...,x_n/x_i] \otimes_A B) \\ &= \bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathrm{Spec}(A[x_0/x_i,...,\widehat{x_i/x_i},...,x_n/x_i]) \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)} \mathrm{Spec}(B) \\ & = P_A^n \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}\mathrm{Spec}(B) \end{align*}$$
The equalities I used follow from the facts that if $B,C$ are $A$-algebras then $A[x_1,...,x_k]\otimes_{A}B \cong B[x_1,...,x_k]$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(B\otimes_A C) \cong \mathrm{Spec}(B) \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}\mathrm{Spec}(C)$. Both of these are obvious, tell me if you still think it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative approach using the "language of representable functors" that might be of interest. It uses the fact that the projective space bundle represents a certain functor. You avoid having to check that the isomorphisms (defined locally) above glue to global isomorphisms.

If $\phi: A \rightarrow B$
with $S:=Spec(B), T:=Spec(A)$ and where $V:=A\{e_0,..,e_n\}$ and $V^*:=A\{x_0,..,x_n\}$.
Let $E^*:=p^*V^*:=B\otimes_A V^*$ where

$p: S \rightarrow T$

is the canonical map. We may form the projective space bundle $\mathbb{P}(V^*):=Proj(Sym_A^*(V^*))$ and projection map

$\pi_T: \mathbb{P}(V^*) \rightarrow T$.

By functoriality of this construction it follows the fiber product $S\times_T \mathbb{P}(V^*) $ satisfies the formula

I0. $S\times_T \mathbb{P}(V^*) \cong \mathbb{P}(p^* V^*)\cong \mathbb{P}(E^*).$

Let $F_{V^*}: Sch(T)\rightarrow Sets$

be the "well known" functor

$F_{V^*}(X,f):=\{ f^*V^* \rightarrow L \rightarrow 0\}/\cong$

where $L \in Pic(T)$. There is an isomorphism of functors

$F_{V^*}(-) \cong h_{\mathbb{P}(V^*)}(-)$.

(I believe this follows from Proposition II.7.12 in Hartshorne.)

Let

$F_{p^*V^*}: Sch(S) \rightarrow Sets$

be the functor

$F_{p^*V^*}(Y,g)=\{ g^*p^*V^* \rightarrow L \rightarrow 0 \}/\cong$

where $L\in Pic(S)$. Since $F_{p^*V^*}(-)\cong h_{\mathbb{P}(p^*V^*)}(-)$
and since there is a canonical projection map

$\pi_S : \mathbb{P}(p^*V^*) \rightarrow S$, we get a canonical map

$j:\mathbb{P}(p^*V^*) \rightarrow S\times_T \mathbb{P}(V^*)$.

At the level of functors, it maps the element $g^*p^*V^*\rightarrow L \rightarrow 0$ in $F_{p^*V^*}(Y,g)$ to the element $(p\circ g)^*V^* \rightarrow L \rightarrow 0$ in  $F_{V^*}(Y, p \circ g)$.

It should follow from Proposition II.7.12 in Hartshorne that the above constructed map is an isomorphism, proving that I0 is an isomorphism. To write down all the details in this proof is an exercise in the "language representable functors".

Since $\mathbb{P}(V^*):=Proj(A[x_0,..,x_n]):=\mathbb{P}^n_{Spec(A)}$ and $\mathbb{P}(E^*):=Proj(B[x_0,..,x_n]):=\mathbb{P}^n_{Spec(B)}$

we get an isomorphism

I1. $Spec(B)\times_{Spec(A)} \mathbb{P}^n_{Spec(A)} \cong \mathbb{P}^n_{Spec(B)}$.

Example 1. Let $A:=\mathbb{Z}$ be the ring of integers. It follows for any commutative unital ring $B$ there is an isomorphism

$ Spec(B)\times_{Spec(\mathbb{Z})}\mathbb{P}^n_{Spec(\mathbb{Z})}\cong \mathbb{P}^n_{Spec(B)}$.

Example 2. Let $u:Spec(\kappa(x))\rightarrow T$ be a point in $T$. it follows there is an isomorphism

$\pi_T(x):=Spec(\kappa(x))\times_T \mathbb{P}(V^*)\cong \mathbb{P}(\kappa(x)\otimes_A V^*) \cong \mathbb{P}^n_{\kappa(x)}$.

Hence the fiber of $\pi_T$ at $x$ is projective $n$-space over the residue field $\kappa(x)$ of $x$. Hence for different points $x,y \in T$ it follows
the fibers of $\pi_T$ at $x,y$ will be projective spaces over "different fields". Their characteristic may differ.

Example 3. Rings of integers in number fields. Let $K$ be any number field and let $E$ be a rank $d+1$ projective $\mathcal{O}_K$-module. Let $T:=Spec(\mathcal{O}_K)$ and let $\pi: \mathbb{P}(E^*)\rightarrow T$ be the projective space bundle of $E$. For any closed point $x\in T$ it follows the fiber of $\pi$ at $x$ is $\mathbb{P}^d_{\kappa(x)}$ and the residue field $\kappa(x)$ is a finite field. Let $U:=Spec(A) \subseteq T$ be an open subscheme where $E$ trivialize: $E(U)\cong A\{e_0,..,e_d\}$. It follows

$\pi^{-1}(U) \cong U\times_T \mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{Z}}$.

This example illustrates the difference between this viewpoint and the viewpoint in complex analytic geometry and differential geometry. The fiber of a complex holomorphic vector bundle (or projective bundle) is affine space (or projective space) over the complex numbers. The fibers of the map $\pi$ constructed above are defined over fields where the characteristic may vary.