# Projective $n$-space over a ring $B$, denoted $P^n_B$ over a ring $B$ isomorphic to fibred product $P^n_A\times \text{Spec}(B)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne, AG, p. 103, it says that we have the isomorphism of the projective $n$-space $P^n_B$ to $P^n_A\times_{\text{Spec}(A)}\text{Spec}(B)$ with an underlying ring homomorphism $\phi: A\rightarrow B$. I would like to remind that by definition $P^n_B=\text{Proj } B[x_0,...,x_n]$ and $P^n_A=\text{Proj } A[x_0,...,x_n]$.

What does this isomorphism map look like?

I am completely clueless how to approach this question. Considering the generators of a homogeneous prime ideal of $P^n_B$ denoting them  $g_1,...,g_r$, each being elements of $\text{Proj}$ $B[x_0,...,x_n]$, I might apply $\phi^{-1}$ to the the coefficients (in $B$) of $g_j$ to each generator $g_j,j=1,...r$, but I do not really see how this may be helpful.

Comment: Your last paragraph isn't really appropriate here. Instead, look at the construction of the fiber product: cover $\Bbb P^n_A$ by the standard affine open sets, compute the fiber product there, then glue back together and realize you have exactly $\Bbb P^n_B$. (I'm sure there's a duplicate for this out there, but I haven't found it yet.)

Comment: @KReiser You might be sure since you answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905834/explicit-proof-that-mathbbp-bn-cong-mathbbp-an-times-operatornamespec?noredirect=1&lq=1) a couple years ago! This may also answer your question OP.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the assist in finding two potential duplicate targets! I'll likely close this as a duplicate soon, once the OP has had some time to respond.